# zlib c decompress

Tags: c, wrapper, zlib

I'm looking for a simple C Wrapper of zlib, to decompress a byte array. Anyone knows one ?

Comment: Did you mean a C# wrapper? zlib is written in C itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267455/c-cross-platform-zlib-simplifer-wrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By wrapper function, you probably mean some simpler to use, more self-contained functions?

Zlib contains them. Have a look in the [manual](https://zlib.net/manual.html) under "Utility Functions".

You're probably look for:

> ```
> ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT uncompress OF((Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen,
>                                    const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));
> ```

Comment: That's what i'm looking for, but it doesn't exist in my zlib.h :/

Comment: oh sorry it does, just overlooked it..^^