# Is there any cross-platform gzip processor library for C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, open-source, gzip

I want some library (API) to open, seek, read, write ... (in one word **to process**) gzip files. Is there any open-source cross-platform ones for C or C++?

Comment: Have you looked at zlib?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) is the one.

There is also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267455/c-cross-platform-zlib-simplifer-wrapper) on how to process gzip files more easily and conveniently in C++. The most notable and up to date suggestion seems to be the [GZip filters in Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html), which I have good experience with myself.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, sure, [zlib](http://zlib.net) is the basic library and it has additional bindings other  languages as listed on the webpage as eg [gzstream](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) providing a C++ wrapper to the `gz*` functions.

[zlib](http://zlib.net), being a C-language library, is also extremely portable and cross-platform. See the webpage for links to Solaris, SCO, BeOS, MaxOS, OS/2 (!!), Palm Pilot, Newton (!!), Windows CE (!!), Blackberry, Windows, .Net, ... versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in the magic of Boost, check out Boost's [stream filters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#examples) which can be arbitrarily combined and cascaded; there's built-in support for gzip, DEFLATE (that's GZip minus the header) and bzip2. Very handy.