# Compressing/decompressing data on the go

Tags: c++, compression

I'm running a physics simulation and I'd like to improve the way it is handling its data. I'm saving and reading files that contained one float then two ints followed by 512*512 = 262144 +1 or -1 weighting 595 kb per datafile in the end. All these numbers are separated by a single space.

I'm saving hundreds of thousands of these files so it quickly adds up to gigas of storage, I'd like to know if there is a quick (hopefully light cpu-effort-wise way) of compressing and decompressing this kind of data on the go (I mean not tarring/untarring before/after use).

How much could I expect saving in the end?

Comment: This library should help:

[Is there any cross-platform gzip processor library for C or C++?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372259/is-there-any-cross-platform-gzip-processor-library-for-c-or-c

Comment: It might help but whilst the user has tagged this "compression" they specifically said they want to be light CPU-wise and not have to tar/untar but which I assume they also mean not compress/decompress between usages.

Comment: Is that 262144 instances of the value +1 or -1? Are there any other values it could be?

Comment: I couldn't work that out either, but if so obviously you'd only need one bit per flag. Of course your bits would be 1 or 0.

Comment: @SKizz: yes, it can only be +1 or -1 (equally distributed), actually since my question I updated my program to only save '+' or '-' saving around 25% of space.

Comment: If you have to store them as text, you can still pack 4 into a single byte easily (you could pack in 6 but 4 is easier for you to manage). That would save you even more space.

Comment: Is there a requirement for the files to be human readable?

Comment: So, if you just store the data as bits (without compressing repeated data), it would take 32 KB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want relatively fast read-write, you would probably want to store and read them in "binary" format, i.e. native to the way they are internally stored in bytes. A float uses 4-bytes of data, and you do not need any kind of "separator" when storing a large sequence of them.

To do this you might consider [boost's "serialize" library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Note that using data compression methods (zlib etc) will save you on bytes stored but will be relatively slow to zip and unzip them for usage.

Storing in binary format will not only use less disk storage (than storing in text format) but should also be more performant, not just because there is less file I/O but also because there is no string writing/parsing going on.

Note that when you input/output to `binary_iarchive` or `binary_oarchive` you pass in an underlying `istream` or `ostream` and if this is a file, you need to open it with `ios::binary` flag because of the issue of line-endings being potentially converted.

Even if you do decide that data-compression (zlib or some other library) is the way to go, it is still worth using boost::serialize to get your data into a "blob" to compress. In that case you would probably use `std::ostringstream` as your output stream to create the blob.

Incidentally, if you have 2^18 "boolean" values that can only be 1 or -1, you only need 1 bit for each one, (they would be physically stored as 1 or 0 but you would logically translate that). That would come to 2^15 bytes which is 32K not 595K

Comment: It is worth noting that due to the relative slowness of disk access (even SSDs) as compared to RAM, compressing and decompressing can actually save both time and space. [Snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) is a compression library that focuses on this use case.

Comment: Yes but you still need to get the data first into a "blob" to compress it and so you might use boost-serialize for that.

Comment: Of course. I was only meaning to comment on the paragraph where you say "Note that using data compression methods [...] will be relatively slow", which is not neccessarily true :) Otherwise, I quite like this answer (and have voted accordingly) :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the extra info about the valid data, define your class like this:-

```
class Data
{
  float m_float_value;
  int m_int_value_1, m_int_value_2;
  unsigned m_weights [8192];
};
```

Then use binary file IO to stream this class to and from a file, don't convert to text!

The weights are stored as Boolean values, packed into unsigned integers.

To get the weight, add an accessor:-

```
int Data::GetWeight (size_t index)
{
  return m_weights [index >> 5] & (1 << (index & 31)) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This gives you a data file size of 32780 bytes (5.4%) if there's no packing in the class data.

Comment: Oh, and I meant to add: Not sure evenly distributed data can be reliably compressed, most compression requires some data redundancy to achieve lossless compression, which I don't think you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if you are concerned about size a binary format would be the most useful way to "compress" your data. It sounds like you are dealing with something like the following:

```
struct data {
    float a;
    int b, c;
    signed char d[512][512];
};

someFunc() {
    data* someData = new data;

    std::ifstream inFile("inputData.bin", std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream outFile("outputData.bin", std::ofstream::binary);

    // Read from file
    inFile.read(someData, sizeof(data));
    inFile.close();

    // Write to file
    outFile.write(someData, sizeof(data));
    outFile.close();

    delete someData;
}
```

I should also mention then if you encode your +1/-1 as bits you should get a lot of space savings (another factor of 8 on top of what I'm showing here).

Answer (score 0):

For that amount of data, anything homemade isn't going perform anywhere near as well as good-quality open-source binary-storage libraries. Try [boost serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or - for this type of storage requirement - [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5).  I've used HDF5 successfully on a few projects with very very large amounts of `double`, `float`, `long` and `int` data .  Found it useful one can control the compression-rate *vs* cpu-effort on the fly per "file".  Also useful is storing millions of "files" in a hierarchically-structured single "disk" file.  NASA - probably ripping my style;) - also uses it.